# List Model Stops Binding Correctly When Query Parameter is Added

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am using a modal editor dialog to allow a user to modify a list of customer addresses.  When the customer wants to add or remove an address, I handle it with JQuery using an AJAX request.  Despite the fact that the code is basically cut and paste with minor changes, my `addAddr()` function is working as expected (the controller receives a list of addresses), while my `delAddr()` function is not working (the controller receives a list with one address, despite the fact that the model contains multiple addresses.)  Can anybody see the bug in the following code?

Controller Actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCustomerAddress(List<CustomerAddress> Model)
{
    var newAddr = new CustomerAddress
    {
        CustomerID = Model[0].CustomerID,
        IsActive = true,
        IsPrimary = true
    };

    await _dbService.InsertCustomerAddressAsync(newAddr);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(EditCustomerAddresses), new { Model[0].CustomerID });
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomerAddress(List<CustomerAddress> Model, [FromQuery]int Index)
{
    await _dbService.DeleteCustomerAddressAsync(Model[Index]);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(EditCustomerAddresses), new { Model[0].CustomerID });
}
```

JQuery:

```
function addAddr() {
    var model = $('form#addr-editor').serialize();
    $.post('/Customer/AddCustomerAddress',
        model,
        function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            $('#modal-container').html(data);
            $.notify('New Address Activated - Save Changes After Editing', { position: "top-center" });
        }
    ).fail(function () {
        $.notify('Error adding Address.', { position: "top center" });
    });
}

function delAddr(index) {
    var model = $('form#addr-editor').serialize();
    $.post('/Customer/DeleteCustomerAddress?Index=' + index,
        model,
        function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            $('#modal-container').html(data);
            $.notify('Address Deleted Successfully', { position: "top center" });
        }
    ).fail(function () {
        $.notify('Error Deleting Address.', { position: "top center" });
    });
}
```

My test record has six addresses.  The Add action receives a `List<CustomerAddress>` with `Count = 6`.  The Delete action receives the Index properly, but it receives the model as a `List<CustomerAddress>` with `Count = 1`.  The only difference that I am aware of is the inclusion of an additional parameter in the query string.  My desired behavior is for both controller actions to receive a list of 6 addresses.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you verity in the network tab that the request is sending all 6 when you are trying to delete?

Comment: @nurdyguy - I just checked using PostMan... both AJAX posts show all 6 addresses being sent in Body x-www-form-urlencoded.  That would suggest that the JQuery is working as expected and there is an issue in the controller action (or some nuance to model binding that I'm not aware of)

Comment: Try using a route attribute, something like `[HttpPost, Route("/Customer/DeleteCustomerAddress/{int:index}")]` and adjust the controller method and ajax url accordingly.

Comment: @nurdyguy - Good idea, but I tried and got the same behavior.  I think I just got to the bottom of it - the parameter name "Index" must be reserved - changing the parameter name to something else solved the problem.  Adding [FromForm] before the model also works.  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Interesting find.  Glad things are working for you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue - it appears this is a feature, not a bug...  Changing the action signature to something like this solves the problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomerAddress(List<CustomerAddress> Model, [FromQuery]int NotTheIndex)
{
    await _dbService.DeleteCustomerAddressAsync(Model[NotTheIndex]);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(EditCustomerAddresses), new { Model[0].CustomerID });
}
```

This suggests that `Index` is a reserved parameter name.  When I was getting one entry in my list, and the index was 2, I was actually getting only `Model[2]`.

Adding `FromForm` before the `Model` also solves the problem:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomerAddress([FromForm]List<CustomerAddress> Model, [FromQuery]int Index)
```